# How can I procees the below text file for text classification? I would like each paragraph as a row in a pandas dataframe, I am unable to do that

Tags: python, machine-learning

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbOLA.jpg)

```
                        1
```

Loren ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

There are 154 such paragraphs, I would like to read each paragraph as a row in python.please see the image for a clear example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f = open('sample_text.txt', 'r')
data = f.read()
paragraphs = data.split("\n\n")
paragraphs[:] = (value for value in paragraphs if value != '\t')
```

Comment: Providing some explanation will be helpful for future readers to understand your answer.

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro Please pay attention when reviewing. There is no link to be seen in this answer, so the review option you chose was inappropriate.